# Is there a scope or some other way to suspend the computer from unity dash?

Tags: unity, suspend

I want to type suspend in the dash to suspend my computer. Unity does not have this functionality by default. Is there a scope which provides this?

Comment: What is the problem with the upper right icon next to your username to suspend your computer? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Marc-AndréAppel, Win + 'sus' is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Unity has options to make you shut down your computer, log off, and restart if you type "log" on Unity Dash. However, the option to suspend doesn't exist. Of all scopes that I've ever seen, none had that feature...